# Set color for segments in ggnet

Tags: r, networking, ggplot2

I hvar the following data set:

```
structure(c(2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 
2L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 
8L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 
2L, 44L, 79L, 10L, 8L, 47L, 45L, 51L, 9L, 11L, 74L, 75L, 77L, 
69L, 75L, 77L, 78L, 2L, 44L, 44L, 46L, 46L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 
9L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 
10L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 44L, 
10L, 9L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 46L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L), .Dim = c(66L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to", "impact")))
```

The data set indicates, a connection between from and to with a positive (1) or negative (-1) impact.

I would like to plot a network graph with ggnet (or ggplot2) that plot this graph.

So far I have done the following steps:

```
library(network)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnet)
library(grid)

net <- network(df2[,c(1,2)], directed = FALSE)

ggnet(net, mode = 'kamadakawai', size = 6, alpha = .5, label.nodes=F, segment.alpha = 0.5, color = "black") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"))
```

This lead to this result:
[image]

I am wondering how to colorize the edges based on the impact in the dataset (1 = green and -1 = red). I am also wondering why there are so many unconnected nodes...

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please can you mention the packages you have used

Comment: @user2510479: I used `library(network)` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/network.pdf), `library(ggnet)` (https://github.com/briatte/ggnet) and `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: I think the grid package was also used

Comment: Oh right, I updated it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am using `GGally::ggnet` as this is available through CRAN. I believe this is equivalent to that on github.

```
library(network)
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
# dependencies
library(grid)
library(sna)
library(intergraph)
```

The reason you have many unconnected nodes in your network diagram is because the node names you have supplied are not an unbroken sequence of integers. For example, if you supply only an edge between nodes named `1` and `10`, `network()` will assume the presence of eight unconnected nodes with names `2:9`. For example,

```
netwk1 <- network(cbind(1,2), directed = F)
get.vertex.attribute(netwk1, attrname="vertex.names")
netwk2 <- network(cbind(1,10), directed = F)
get.vertex.attribute(netwk2, attrname="vertex.names")
```

So if you convert your node names to an unbroken sequence, you will lose all the unconnected nodes. So something like:

```
df2[,1:2]=as.numeric(as.factor(df2[,c(1,2)]))
net <- network(df2[,c(1,2)], directed = F)
ggnet(net, mode = 'kamadakawai', size = 6, alpha = .5, label.nodes=T, segment.alpha = 0.5, color = "black") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"))
```

You can color the edges with the `segment.color` argument in `ggnet()` :

```
edge_color = ifelse(df2[,3]==-1, "red", "green")
ggnet(net, mode = 'kamadakawai', size = 6, alpha = .5, segment.color=edge_color, label.nodes=T, segment.alpha = 0.5, color = "black") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"))
```

Comment: I see. In my version I used the node names, not the numbers, thats what makes the difference... Your code works perfectly. Thanks for the help and the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You should include node.group =type

```
   ggnet(net, mode = 'kamadakawai', size = 6, alpha = .5, label.nodes=F, segment.alpha = 0.5, color = "black", node.group=type) +
   theme(legend.position = "none")+
   theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1), "cm"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also construct the plot directly using the [network](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/network/index.html) package, which I think ggnet is using under the hood.

```
# Dominik's data structure
edgelist<-structure(c(2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 
2L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 
8L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 
2L, 44L, 79L, 10L, 8L, 47L, 45L, 51L, 9L, 11L, 74L, 75L, 77L, 
69L, 75L, 77L, 78L, 2L, 44L, 44L, 46L, 46L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 
9L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 
10L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 44L, 
10L, 9L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 46L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L), .Dim = c(66L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("from", "to", "impact")))

# construct a network object
net<-as.network.matrix(edgelist,matrix.type='edgelist',
                    ignore.eval=FALSE,names.eval='impact')

# plot it, using the impact edge attribute to control edge color
plot(net,edge.col=ifelse(net%e%'impact'==1,'green','red'))
```

[image]

Nate Pope's answer above about changing the range of the ids to remove isolates still applies.  However, you can ask plot.network not to draw the isolates:

```
plot(net,edge.col=ifelse(net%e%'impact'==1,'green','red'),displayisolates=FALSE)
```

[image]